# First non zero result bitwise AND python

Tags: python

In numbers like `16`, performing bitwise `AND` on all numbers from `1` to `15` gives result `0`. I want to find out the first number that doesn't give `0` when bitwise `AND` is performed on it.

TLDR : Find smallest `x` such that `x AND y ! = 0`

`y` is given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to find the first bit from right, which is 1.
For example,

```
y = 16 = 0b10000
           ^
y = 12 = 0b1100
            ^
```

```py
def get_x(y):
    i = 0
    while True:
        if (y >> i) & 1 == 1:
            break
        i += 1
    return 1 << i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do brute force approach:

```py
while True:
    y=int(input('y='))
    x=1
    while True:
        if(x & y !=0):
            print(x)
            break
        x*=2
```

Comment: is there a logical method possible? because I need this  for big numbers

Comment: A less ‘brute force’ method is ‘x = x * 2’ instead of x+=1

Comment: can x be found straight away from the binary expansion?

Comment: No, you still need a loop to find the lowest 1 digit.

Answer (score 0):

This seems cleverer.

```py
def get_x(y):
    return y & (-y)
```

[Find the lowest set bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247186/find-the-lowest-set-bit)