# how does below bit manipulation code works?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```java
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    int s=4;
    int k=3;
    int a=s^k;
    int b=a & -a;
    System.out.println(b);
  } 
}
```

- 

I have compiled the above code it gives 1 as the output.
But I can't get that how it is compiling.
if I do XOR OPERATION between s and k it will give 111(7).
but  don't  know how `b=a & -a`  working please explain.*

Comment: Find out what representation is used for -7. What pattern of bits is it?

Comment: I would recommend doing `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(a));` + `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-a));` to see the binary representation of those values. That would probably clear things up

Comment: `a & -a` is an [idiom to get the lowest set bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12247186/555045)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-a)) will print 11111111111111111111111111111001

Comment: @SanuraHettiarachchi Which is correct because integers are 32 bit in java. In your answer you ignore that fact and treat the ints as if they are 3 bit, which isn't the case in java. The binary representation of 7 in java is 00000000000000000000000000000111, and its two-compliment is therefor 11111111111111111111111111111001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it in binary.

```
s = 100
k = 011
```

[image]

```
a = s^k = 100 ^ 011 = 111
```

To get negative number invert all digits and add 1

```
    -a = invert a + 1 = 000 + 001 = 001
    
     a & -a = 111 & 001 = 001 = decimal 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### -x == ~x + 1

#### Negative is ones-complement + 1

```
Should  x     be ababab10..0 (repeated zeros at the end)
then    ~x    is bababa01..1
then   ~x+1   is bababa10..0
then   x&-x   is 0....010..0
```

### So `x & -x` gives the right most bit 1 of x.

For 7 that would be 1; 12 -> 4, 6 -> 2, 14 -> 2, 8 -> 8, 24 -> 8.

To count the number of bits:

```
int bitCount(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        n ^= (n & -n); // Remove the right-most bit.
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```