# Using AND bitwise operator between a number, and its negative counterpart

Tags: c++, c, integer, bit, bitwise-and

I stumbled upon this simple line of code, and I cannot figure out what it does. I understand what it does in separate parts, but I don't really understand it as a whole.

```
// We have an integer(32 bit signed) called i
// The following code snippet is inside a for loop declaration
// in place of a simple incrementor like i++ 
// for(;;HERE){}
i += (i&(-i))
```

If I understand correctly it uses the AND binary operator between i and negative i and then adds that number to i. I first thought that this would be an optimized way of calculating the absolute value of an integer, however as I come to know, c++ does not store negative integers simply by flipping a bit, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to do some exploration of your own. Write a program that prints out `i` and `(i&(-i))` in a loop to see what the values are. Figure out the binary representation of the values (either by hand or with a program) to find the pattern

Comment: *c++ does not store negative integers simply by flipping a bit*. AFAIK C23 mandates the use of two's complement for negative integer values.

Comment: You need to specify which language you are asking for (you tagged both C and C++) and which version. The rules regarding integer representation aren't necessarily the same across languages or versions.

Comment: You ask about absolute value: with two's complement integers it can be implemented as `(x + (x >> N)) ^ (x >> N)` where `N` is the size of the type in bits -1.

Comment: this code invokes UB if `i` is  `INT_MIN`

Comment: if you think it is `i++`, think again https://godbolt.org/z/6f9v8Mrd3

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're probably right, I can't however give a specific version or language, since this was not defined in the original code.

Comment: @botiapa assume two's complement and do not think too much about the language standard.

Comment: @Kevin That's exactly what I did, but I couldn't figure out any pattern.

Comment: @0___________ Hmm. I'm trying to find a pattern, but it's quite hard. What I found is that when only 1 bit equals one, then the two numbers match.

Comment: @botiapa https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12250963/5522303 (the question/answer are javascript, but the algorithm is the same)

Comment: @botiapa The next time you can't figure out a pattern, you might try using [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org). For instance, this one is [A006519](https://oeis.org/A006519).

Comment: @EricMSchmidt Thank you so much, this is a great resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming two's complement representation, and assuming `i` is not `INT_MIN`, the expression `i & -i` results in the value of the lowest bit set in `i`.

If we look at the value of this expression for various values of `i`:

```
 0 00000000: i&(-i) = 0
 1 00000001: i&(-i) = 1
 2 00000010: i&(-i) = 2
 3 00000011: i&(-i) = 1
 4 00000100: i&(-i) = 4
 5 00000101: i&(-i) = 1
 6 00000110: i&(-i) = 2
 7 00000111: i&(-i) = 1
 8 00001000: i&(-i) = 8
 9 00001001: i&(-i) = 1
10 00001010: i&(-i) = 2
11 00001011: i&(-i) = 1
12 00001100: i&(-i) = 4
13 00001101: i&(-i) = 1
14 00001110: i&(-i) = 2
15 00001111: i&(-i) = 1
16 00010000: i&(-i) = 16
```

We can see this pattern.

Extrapolating that to `i += (i&(-i))`, assuming `i` is positive, it adds the value of the lowest set bit to `i`.  For values that are a power of two, this just doubles the number.

For other values, it rounds the number up by the value of that lowest bit.  Repeating this in a loop, you eventually end up with a power of 2.  As for what such an increment could be used for, that depends on the context of where this expression was used.